# Unable to get index path of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view with dynamic cells constructed with `autolayout`. I have a `UITextView` as subview inside UITableViewCell . This `UITextView` can grow vertically i.e scroll is disabled for this text view and it's height constraint is equal to cell content view's height. So whenever textview height increases then corresponding cell's height will also increase.

I need to get indexpath of any given cell.
When textview height becomes higher than screen height then `indexPathForCell` returns nil. I also tried `indexPathForRowAtPoint:[cell center]` it also returns nil. I cannot get indexpath from my model cells array since model don't have my cell (cell was already deleted from model array).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      NSMutableArray *cellArray = [tableViewCellsDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:sectionIndex]];
      return [cellArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
  }

-(void) updateTextViewTextInCell:(CustomCell *) cell {
      NSIndexPath *currentCellIndexPath1 = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];  // Returns nil
      NSIndexPath *currentCellIndexPath2 = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[cell center]]; // Returns nil
}
```

I call this `updateCellTextView` method from `textViewDidEndEditing` to save the textview's text in my model.

But I'm not able to get indexpath of cell.

How to get index path of a cell in this kind of scenarios i.e when cell is completely out of screen .

[image]

Comment: Don't make people guess. Update your question with actual, relevant code.

Comment: That's not enough code. Post the whole method containing that line. Include any other relevant details.

Comment: @JafferSheriff Can you post the method where you want the indexPath of cell. and `cellForRow` also

Comment: Why aren't you using proper cell dequeueing?

Comment: My cell's UI differs greatly from each other and also they are not symmetric so I use static cells array.

Comment: In asysmetricity, put conditions, like this you never get cell, You get cell indexpath like this only if it the delegate property of tableView

Comment: @JafferSheriff Can you  explain, what actually you are trying to do, may be we find some other better solution.

Comment: I have UITableView with 2 sections. I have add button in the section header view. When user tap that button I insert 3 cells i.e 1st cell have delete button and remaining 2 cells have UITextView as subview. Consider user started typing in text view and presses add button in header view. I add cells in model and then I have to update the data in model. So I call  `updateTextViewTextInCell`  from `textViewDidEndEditing` to update data. I need to get index of cell that contains the UITextView.  So i use `indexPathForCell` method to get index path.

Comment: Can you show me your UI screenshot.

Comment: I think this all fields are `UITextField` not `UItextView`.

Comment: Nope they are all UITextViews

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132258/discussion-between-the-dahiya-boy-and-jaffer-sheriff).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `indexpath` of cell in `textViewDidEndEditing` you can use this code.

```
 CGPoint point = [textView convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableview];
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you never get `indexpath` of cell like this because this is only applicable in the `UItableViewDelegates and UItableViewDatasource methods`.

As per I understand, Now you need to know on which `UITextView` user is end texting. So one of the better approach is as below :

1. in `cellForRow`

`cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row`

Here you have assigned tag to the `textView` which is equivalent to its `indexpath.row`. Now when ever you are talking about `textView.tag`, it gives you the `textView` of that particular cell and `textView.tag` is that particular cell you have `TextView`

2. in `- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(TextView *)textView`

   ```
   textView.tag // gives you indexPath.row of the textview where user ends editing
   ```

**NOTE :** If you have `UITextView/UItextfield`in `UItableView`, its value is always lost whenever your cell is out of screen. So to overwhelm this problem use dictionary save the each and every value of  `UITextView/UItextfield` in `TextdidChange Method`.

Hope now you got it.

Comment: I have to handle deletion of cells too. So as per your solution I have to reassign `tag` of cells to textview's tag during each deletion. So it add such compications

Comment: For deletion give tog to your `cell.btnDelete = indexPath.section` (assuming you have to delete complete section). On `btnDelete:(UIButton*)sender`: **1)** Remove the data of that section i.e. `UITextView` of that section from the dictionary **2)** decrease your `numberOfSection` **3)** reload `UITableView`.

Comment: @JafferSheriff **NOTE :** you have to maintain the `UITextVIew` data in dictionary properly, such that whenever you reload `tableView` correct data will be appear in its respective `UITextView`